# Is it possible to preview a 'Squash and merge' on GitHub?

Tags: github

I have a pull request from branch `new-files` that contains contributions from multiple authors.

[image: Commits from multiple authors]

Before I [squash and merge](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits) this pull request into `master`, I would like to preview the squashed commit so I can see who will be listed as the final author.

[While it is possible to preview a local git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git), I don't fully trust that my local result would be exactly the same as merging with GitHub's squash and merge.

[image: squash and merge example]

Is there a way to preview the result of a 'Squash and merge' on GitHub before actually merging?

Comment: Do you want to run tests against it? What would you like to preview?

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to figure out who the author/committer of the merged commit would be.

Comment: This is briefly covered in the documentation https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#common-reasons-that-contributions-are-not-counted